# When opening up my bash terminal a while loop git message pops up, how do I remove it

Tags: git, bash, terminal

When I boot up my bash terminal this is what comes up

```
-bash:  | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done && git fetch --all && git pull --all: No such file or directory
```

How do I remove this message. I checked MOTD, it's not that, I checked .bashrc, .bash_profile, and various .bash_* but there is no script running in there that would make it check git.

This is my Mac Terminal

Comment: Does the message repeat if you run `bash` or `bash -l`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific to the macOS Terminal application, you may have this configured as the "run command" in Terminal itself.

In Terminal's Preferences, under the "Profiles" section, there is a text field labeled "Run Command". If this command is in that box, simply remove it (or uncheck the box that runs the specified command).

This setting exists for each available profile, so you may have to look through various profiles to find it (if you aren't sure which profile you are using currently).

[image]

It is also possible that you have set up a framework like [Bash-it](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it), and it is responsible for this, using a git plugin. If you are using something like that, check its configuration file for configured plugins.

Beyond that, I would check *all* of the files bash will read on startup. You can find details of bash's startup in `man bash`, section "INVOCATION". Here is a list of files I found there.

- `/etc/profile`
- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bash_login`
- `~/.profile`
- `~/.bashrc`
- A file pointed to by environment variable `$BASH_ENV`
- A file pointed to by environment variable `$ENV` (if invoked as `sh`)
- `~/.bash_logout` (on logout only)

For completeness I'll add to that list `/etc/bashrc`, which is where the OP indicated the problem was eventually located.

Comment: Hey, Yeah the Profiles section startup is clear, I checked that before hand

Comment: It's something deeper, and I also don't have any ooutside frameworks running

Comment: @BkRazor See my updated answer for a list of startup files you should take a look at. It's also possible one of these files is calling another file that contains the actual git stuff you're seeing.

Comment: Finally found it thank you, it was actually in /etc/bashrc